# Filter Parent Collection Using Criteria in Child Collection via a Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have the following graph of entities:

```
Item
  IList<Prices>     
  DateTime Opened
  DateTime? Closed 

Price
  Name
  DateTime Opened
  DateTime? Closed
```

How to select all items where `Closed` is null and only prices where `Closed` is null?

As you can see `Item` and `Price` have valid period, so I need select only valid Items and with valid Prices.

I know how to select items, but I don't know how to constrain "nested" prices.

```
Items.Where(i => i.Closed == null).Where(i => i.Prices <need constraint prices>)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're probably looking for something like this?

```
Items.Where(i => !i.Closed.HasValue && i.Prices.Any(p => !p.Closed.HasValue))
```

That will only select items that have a non-closed price.

If you want to actually get a list of non-closed prices per item, I'd switch to LINQ syntax and do something like this:

```
from i in Items
where !i.Closed.HasValue
from p in i.Prices
where !p.Closed.HasValue
group p by i into itemPrices
select new {
    Opened = i.Opened
    Closed = i.Closed
    Items = itemPrices
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Prices.All`?

Comment: It depends on what the requirement is - Any() will filter items that have at least one non-closed price, All() will ensure that the items have *only* non-closed prices.

Comment: yes i know, and i was under the impression the requirement was the latter. i could have misread the q though.

Comment: Actually it looks more like he wants what's in the 2nd snippet anyways.

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
    items
        .Where(x => x.Closed == null)
        .Select(x =>
            new Item
            {
                Closed = x.Closed,
                Opened = x.Opened,
                Prices = new List<Price>(x.Prices.Where(p => p.Closed == null))
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from item in items
where item.Closed == null
let prices = from price in item.Prices
             where price.Close == null
             select price
select new
{
    Item = item,
    Prices = prices.ToArray()
}
```